# How to expose vault HTTPS API that installed in k8s to outside clients

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, https, client, hashicorp-vault

i have a problem finding explanations on how to expose HTTPS API to outside clients.
The [Vault on Kubernetes Reference Architecture](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/kubernetes-reference-architecture?in=vault/kubernetes)
page ends with a short explanation in the end of this page which leave with no more info on how to
configure vault HTTPS API to be accessible to the outside world .
this [tutorial](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/getting-started-apis?in=vault/getting-started)  using disable TLS
or this [tutorial](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/agent-kubernetes)
which working on minicube , which act differently then real k8s and its also without TLS
[the funny thing is that the main tutorial configuration the vault server cluster in k8s  do use TLS](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/kubernetes-raft-deployment-guide?in=vault/kubernetes)

I just want to make curl API with TLS that will give me the password i set
How do i do this ?